# Make timer stop when user click on play on video

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I have a video on another video. Now it works like, the first video closes after 20 seconds and user will be send to the secound video, but I want that when user clicks the play on the first video, the timer will be stopped and do not close the first videon after 20 seconds. What should I do?

here are my codes

```
<div id="luong_video_ads">
  <div id="luong_video_ads_mes">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <p style="color: #565656; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Ad will be closed   in <span id="luong_video_ads_c"></span> seconds
      </p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:30px;">
      <input type="button" style="background: #ffe100; color: #474747; float: right; border:   1px solid #474747; border-radius: 5px; "value="Skip Ad" onclick="luong_video_ads_showMainVideo();">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both;"/>
  <div id="luong_video_ads_player">
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
luong_video_ads_time_wait = 30;
luong_video_ads_showed = 0;
luong_video_ads_embed = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/17618255"    width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen   allowFullScreen></iframe>';
luong_video_ads_main_embed = '<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie"    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Fcx-bRni7WM?   version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen"    value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed    src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Fcx-bRni7WM?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1"    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always"    allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>';
function luong_video_ads_showAdsVideo(){
  document.getElementById("luong_video_ads_c").innerHTML = luong_video_ads_time_wait;
  document.getElementById("luong_video_ads_player").innerHTML = luong_video_ads_embed;
}
function luong_video_ads_showMainVideo(){
  if (luong_video_ads_showed>0)
    return;
    luong_video_ads_showed = 1;
    document.getElementById("luong_video_ads_player").innerHTML =     luong_video_ads_main_embed;
    document.getElementById("luong_video_ads_mes").style.display = 'none';
}
luong_video_ads_int=self.setInterval(function(){luong_video_ads_clock()},1000);
function luong_video_ads_clock(){
  luong_video_ads_time_wait--;
    if (luong_video_ads_time_wait==0){
      luong_video_ads_showMainVideo();
    }
  document.getElementById("luong_video_ads_c").innerHTML = luong_video_ads_time_wait;
}
luong_video_ads_showAdsVideo();


</script>
```

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the timer by removing it

```
window.clearInterval(intervalVariable);
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for more options

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it possible for you to add it on my codes and update it, so i dont add it in wrong place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at something like http://videojs.com/ - you can embed vimeo as well.

This supports callbacks and event listeners, so you could easily run functions on play/pause and when the video has ended.

Comment: i will not add videmo or youtube embed code, i will add my own video player. Is it works with them too?